# can you select from a table while an index is being rebuilt?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Unable to find this:  A table has an index, and while that index is being rebuilt, the table is locked.  I understand you cannot update or insert into the table while it is locked.  Are you able to still select from that table while the index is being rebuilt?

Thank you.

EDIT:  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

Comment: index rebuilt on online mode?

Comment: Rebuilt without the online option.

Comment: @Mike well, that depends on the engine version..

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008 R2, Enterprise.

Comment: @Mike you should update the question accordingly-it's easier for contributors to help you. And no, you cannot select until the rebuild is done. Even if you would use the `with(nolock)` hint, it wouldn't be able to go through that. Read more about this on [this thread's answer by Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53677/what-is-blocking-select-withnolock)

Comment: I think your comment answers my question.  Thanks!  I'd mark it as the answer, but I'm not sure if I can do that to a comment.